# What is happening when you use the |= operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, assignment-operator

If I'm using something like this:

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

What precisely is the `|=` accomplishing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`|=` is a shortcut for OR'ing two values together and assigning the result to the first variable.

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags = xr.Settings.ValidationFlags | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

`|` is the OR operator in C#, so the code above effectively sets the `ReportValidationWarnings` flag on the value `xr.Settings.ValidationFlags`.

Comment: How does the comparison after the assignment operator actually occur? I know it's comparing the bits, but I'm having a little difficulty getting my head around it.

Comment: It's not comparing bits at all.  If you have two bytes `1001 1101` and you `OR` it with `1100 1011` you would get `1101 1111`.  If a bit it set in either operand, then it is set in the result.  The shorthand of `|=` just states that the left operand of the `OR` is the operand to the left of the `|=`.

Comment: Doesn't the link below indicate that the bitwise comparison is taking place? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. I suppose my confusion lies in something like this: `bool b = true; b |= false;` and yet b still returns true. I feel stupid, but I'm not seeing how that translates into what's happening above.

Comment: `|` means `OR`; If either parameter is true the result is true. In this case it is a bitwise `OR`, which means that if any bit is 1 in either parameter, it stays 1.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are setting `XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings` flag in your `ValidationFlags`.

`|=` is generally bitwise `or` operator, in case of `Flags` it's used to set flag.

Answer (score 1):

This is boolean OR-Equals.

Equivilent to:

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags = xr.Settings.ValidationFlags | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

Which is ensuring that the bits in `XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings` are set.

Answer (score 1):

That is a compound assignment. Essentially you are doing:

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags = 
    xr.Settings.ValidationFlags | 
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
```

Which will essentially add `XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings` to the set of flags contained in `xr.Settings.ValidationFlags`.

Comment: So, why does it do that? I'm having trouble getting my head around the operation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, a |= b is shorthand for a = a | b, in much the same way as a += b is short for a = a + b.
Now what does the | operator do? It can be overloaded, but the general use of it is bit-wise OR. It's similar to the || operator, but it works on a bit by bit basis (think of each bit as a boolean):

false || true is true

0100 | 0110 is 0111

Then the last thing is that one of the classic ways to pass a bunch of boolean flags is to encode them in an integer. A single 32 bit integer can hold 32 individual flags, one per bit. to set a flag, you set the corresponding bit to 1.

So 0000 has no flags set, while 1001 has flags at position 1 and 4 set.

Then |= is a convenient way to set a specific flag.

int my_flags = 0;

my_flag |= validate_flag;

Answer (score 0):

[driis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13958419/1304050) is correct.

`|=` is the same as using the `|` operator in a conditional test, as in the following examples:

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
```

**is semantically identical to**

```
xr.Settings.ValidationFlags = xr.Settings.ValidationFlags | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
```

### Additional note about `|` vs `||`

One additional tidbit I found to be useful was the difference between the [**logical OR**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-) (`|`) and the [**conditional OR**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) (`||`):

The logical OR will always evaluate both operands, even if the first is `true`. The conditional OR will only evaluate the second if the first is `false`, effectively short-circuiting if the execution of the second operand is unnecessary to determine the final result.